# Perl- Get Hash Value from Multi level hash

Tags: perl, loops, hash, key-value

I have a 3 dimension hash that I need to extract the data in it. I need to extract the name and vendor under vuln_soft-> prod. So far, I manage to extract the "cve_id" by using the following code:

```
foreach my $resultHash_entry (keys %hash){
    my $cve_id = $hash{$resultHash_entry}{'cve_id'};
}
```

Can someone please provide a solution on how to extract the name and vendor. Thanks in advance.

```
%hash = {
    'CVE-2015-6929' => {
        'cve_id'    => 'CVE-2015-6929',
        'vuln_soft' => {
            'prod' => {
                'vendor' => 'win',
                'name'   => 'win 8.1',
                'vers'   => {
                    'vers' => '',
                    'num'  => ''
                }
            },            
        'prod' => {
            'vendor' => 'win',
            'name'   => 'win xp',
            'vers'   => {
                'vers' => '',
                'num'  => ''
            }
        }
    },
    'CVE-2015-0616' => {
        'cve_id'    => 'CVE-2015-0616',
        'vuln_soft' => {
            'prod' => {
                'name'   => 'unity_connection',
                'vendor' => 'cisco'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you paste your actual data?  What you show has } with no corresponding {

Comment: The actual data is over 1K lines. I'll try to fix it in the question field.

Comment: To extract data from multidimensional hash use this type of syntax: perl -E '%h=(a=>{b=>1}); say $h{a}{b}'. See also [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-HASHES)

Comment: Where is this hash coming from. This looks suspiciously like you have parsed XML with XML::Simple

Comment: `my $name = $hash{$resultHash_entry}{vuln_soft}{prod}{name}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to initialize a hash, you use `my %hash = (...);` (note the parens, not curly braces). Using `{}` declares a hash reference, which you have done. You should always `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

To answer the question:

```
for my $resultHash_entry (keys %hash){
    print "$hash{$resultHash_entry}->{vuln_soft}{prod}{name}\n";
    print "$hash{$resultHash_entry}->{vuln_soft}{prod}{vendor}\n";
}
```

...which could be slightly simplified to:

```
for my $resultHash_entry (keys %hash){
    print "$hash{$resultHash_entry}{vuln_soft}{prod}{name}\n";
    print "$hash{$resultHash_entry}{vuln_soft}{prod}{vendor}\n";
}
```

because Perl always knows for certain that any deeper entries than the first one is always a reference, so the deref operator `->` isn't needed here.

Comment: I'd like to understand why you've shown the version with the indirection arrow?

Comment: Simply to show where the referencing begins. I can remove it if it detracts from the answer

Comment: No it's fine -- I just wanted to understand your thinking

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, your solution will work only if you have one prod under vuln_soft. If you have more than one prod, it will cause an error Not a hash reference.

Comment: You can't have more than one prod under vuln_soft; hash keys have to be unique. You'll need to show an example of what you mean